# Failed to implement ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies within Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, android-studio-3.5

I am working on a Android application project. It is based on web services and SOAP protocol. I have the ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.JAR library in order to use the classes such as SoapObject. I put it under libs directory and set it as Library.

The error is

> org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution
>   failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException:
>   Execution failed for IdentityTransform: D:\Android\All Crops
>   03-May-19\xxxxxxx\app\libs\ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.5.0.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the event you used a different approach to bring in the jar dependency, these are the steps I took to get it to work:

- I downloaded `...2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar` file from [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/2.4/)
- I verified libs folder exists inside my app module as shown below (if it doesn't, create it):

[image: app/libs]

- Then I pasted the downloaded file into my `app/libs` folder, right-clicked on the jar library and at the bottom of the list, I clicked `Add as Library`:

[image: add as library]

After it auto-generates the gradle dependency, I am able to access and use `SoapObject` in my Activity.

---

I am on MacOs running Android Studio 3.5, using androidx & not the support library: I'm using `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3` instead of `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3`

My gradle distribution is `...gradle-5.4.1-all.zip` and in build.gradle (Project), I'm using 3.5.0:

`dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }`

In gradle.properties, I set `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` also.

If after following the steps above (or if you already did) and it's still not working, you may have to delete your `.gradle` folder and rebuild. This might be because you updated Android Studio to 3.5 but the project's gradle wasn't updated as well.